# How to create a sequence that starts with a number ending in zero?

Tags: excel, vba

Sample comes out like this:

```
12341  
12342  
12343  
12344  
12345  
12346  
12347  
12348  
12349  
12350
```

the first in the sequence should be "12340".

```vb
Sub SerialNumbers()

    Dim Series As Long              ' = Start
    Dim Repeats As Integer          ' = End
    Dim R As Long                   ' row number
    Dim i As Integer                ' repeat counter

    R = NwsFirstDataRow
    With ActiveSheet
        Series = Val(.Cells(R, NwsStart).Value)
        Repeats = Val(.Cells(R, NwsEnd).Value)
        If Repeats Then
            Do While Series > 0
                For i = 1 To Repeats
                    If i > 1 Then
                        R = R + 1
                        .Rows(R).EntireRow.Insert Shift:=xlUp
                    End If
                    .Cells(R, NwsSerial).Value = Series * 10 + i
                Next i
                R = R + 1
                Series = Val(.Cells(R, NwsStart).Value)
            Loop
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: To clarify...you want the sequence to end ...12348, 12349, 12340?

Comment: add this code 
Option Explicit

Enum Nws                            ' Rows & Columns
    NwsFirstDataRow = 2             ' = 1 caption row (adjust as required)
    NwsStart = 1                    ' 1 = column A (adjust as required)
    NwsEnd                          ' no value = previous + 1
    NwsSerial
End Enum

Comment: For your requirement to make sense you would have to supply the values of `Series` and `Repeats` which lead to the result "12341 12342 12343 12344 12345 12346 12347 12348 12349 12350". Presuming that `Series = 1234` and `Repeats = 10`, then what is the result you would prefer in place of the one you quoted? Actually, I think the existing code would produce a result like "12341 12342 12343 12344 12345 12346 12347 12348 12349 123410".

Comment: Sorry (hasty edit). The code does produce the sequence you mention, but I was wondering whether you actually wanted the sequence with the 10 at the end.

Comment: sorry for the confusion i also thought at first that i need is 10 at the end but i realize that what should i need is 0 to 9 sequence. but the code helps a lot.

Comment: What sequence are you expecting if the input values are `1234` for `Series`, and `5` for `Repeats`.  Are you expecting `12341 12342 12343 12344 12340` (i.e. last number in the sequence always ends with 0) or are you expecting `12341 12342 12343 12344 12345`?  And what are you expecting when `Repeats` is `12` - `12341 12342 12343 12344 12345 12346 12347 12348 12349 12350 12351 12340` or `12341 12342 12343 12344 12345 12346 12347 12348 12349 123410 123411 12340`?

Comment: on input values 1234 for series and 5 for repeats i expect that the outcome would be 12341 12342 12343 12344 12345 but if the series is 1234 and the repeats are 10 i expected that the outcome will be 12341 12342 12343...12348 12349 12340 but the outcome is 12341 12342 12343....12348 12349 12350, then i realize that what i need is adding sequence from 0 to 9 if its possible. it should fix to 10 sequences only from 0 to 9

Comment: Hi all thanks for all your concern, now i know the solution. the value of i should be equal to = "0". thanks to all of you sirs! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you require the series to start with zero you should alter the For .. Next loop like this:-

```
    For i = 0 To (Repeats - 1)
        If i Then
            R = R + 1
            .Rows(R).EntireRow.Insert Shift:=xlUp
        End If
        .Cells(R, NwsSerial).Value = Series * 10 + i
    Next i
```